# Limit of function finite not infinite

Tags: warning-messages, special-functions

In long code, I have a function like

```
g[x_] := BesselJ[1, x]/x
```

When I evaluate `g[0]`, where the result should be `1/2`, I instead get the error message

> `Infinite expression 1/0 encountered`

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: By using `Limit` like this `Limit[g[x], x -> 0]`

Comment: you may define a 'safe version' like: `gs[x_] := If[x == 0, Limit[g[x0], x0 -> 0], g[x]]`

Comment: @egwenesedai - rather than evaluate an `If` statement every time the function is called and a `Limit` each time the argument equals zero, just add the additional definition: `g[x_ /; x == 0] = Limit[g[x], x -> 0];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want a representation of the [$\operatorname{jinc}$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JincFunction.html) that doesn't break at $0$, use the Meijer $G$ representation:

```
With[{x = 0}, MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0}, {-1}}, x^2/4]/2]
   1/2
```

but this is expensive; so, just define the function using `Piecewise[]`:

```
jinc[x_] := Piecewise[{{1/2, x == 0}}, BesselJ[1, x]/x]
```